# What causes ilmerge error code -2146232576?

Tags: ilmerge

Running ILMerge on new PC. 
Worked fine on other PC, but now it exits with error -2146232576. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-2146232576 decimal is ‭80131700‬ hex.
Error 0x80131700‬ is "improper installation of .NET framework"
Turns out that ILMerge needs .NET 3.5, which I didn't have installed.
Once I installed the 3.5 framework the error cleared and ILMerge ran successfully.